# Unable to edit LoCo Team wiki pages

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question but I am unable to edit our LoCo Team's wiki pages.  I have a launchpad account and am logged in with my Ubuntu one credentials.  I have been editing our pages since 2015 and earlier this month all of our pages have become immutable.  Is there something new that must be done to enable an individual to edit their own wiki pages?

Comment: There have been some issues with Ubuntu SSO & wiki for the past week...   [rt.ubuntu.com #61049](https://rt.ubuntu.com/Ticket/Display.html?id=61049) which is tracked in a few places (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-wiki-pages-edit/27729/1 UF, IRC etc)

Comment: Wrong spot I'm afraid. I see this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeamContacts and they seem to be active on Libera at #ubuntu-locoteams . Hopefully you can get it sorted :)

Comment: FYI:   If that was your discourse post I provided; thanks for raising it as it got more attention to the thread/ticket Jose opened for our team (Ubuntu News)...

Comment: Thank you guiverc and andrew.46.  I am aware of that activity.  Just thought I might ask here as well.

Comment: Yes that was my discourse post.

Comment: I just noted a message from *Monica/madhens* ... membership on https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wiki-editors may have been dropped possibly because you forgot to *renew* in time (*within a week of the email being sent*... If that's the case, don't forget to *renew* your memberships when they come out (some require renewal every 6 months, others are 12 months, some 24 months.. ie. membership duration varies as do some renewal procedures (*most just require to click on a link*))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied to join the wiki editors team and was approved.  I then logged out of the wiki page and logged back in and the pages are editable.